# form.is_valid() always returns False and form is not valid

Tags: python, django, django-forms

i have a simple form for adding comments and in views i am checking it for validity. But it always returns False and i get error404 according to my code. I have several assumption, but it didn`t work. And now i have no idea how to get the reason
views.py:

```
class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Product
    template_name = "core/product.html"
    context_object_name = "product"
    ....

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.POST.get("product_detail_form") == 'add_comment_form_two':
            if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
                form = CommentForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                    comment = Review(review=request.POST.get("review"),
                                     rating=request.POST.get("rating"),
                                     author=self.request.user,
                                     product_connected=self.get_object())

                    comment.save()
                    print("success ")
                    return redirect("product_detail", *args, **kwargs)
                else:
                    print("error")
                    raise Http404    
                    ....
```

html form

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ comment_form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" name="product_detail_form" 
           value="add_comment_form_two">add comment</input>
</form>
```

forms.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    review = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={"class": "comment_form", "placeholder": "Comment"}), label=""
    )
    OPTIONS = (
        ("1", "1"),
        ("2", "2"),
        ("3", "3"),
        ("4", "4"),
        ("5", "5"),
    )
    rating = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                       choices=OPTIONS)
    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ["review", "rating"]
```

model

```
class Review(models.Model):
    review = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_connected = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                         related_name="reviews")
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_update_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0), 
                                 MaxValueValidator(5)])
```

Thanks for any help, I just can't understand it for a long time.

stupid rule that I have to write less code than question because my question is two sentences

Comment: You should do something with the `form.errors` instead of printing a random string and raising an error

Comment: ok, i`ll try it